# Javascript get the first element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the first element of an array, I can't use [0] because the array is indexed by strings, and I don't know what string correspond to this first element.

Is there any method to get the first element of an array ?

Thanks.

Comment: please add the *array*.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, technically is every index a string.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well… or a symbol. At least keys can be symbols.

Comment: In javascript an array can only have numeric indices. Otherwise it is not an array

Comment: I removed the comment, because a proper explanation is too long for a comment, but there is a technical difficulty with the way this question combines "Array" with "indexed by strings" (implying non-integer-indexes). Yes - Arrays can have non-integer-index properties, as objects, but that completely negates all implications of the word "Array".

Answer (score 0):

As @ASDFGerte mentioned in his comment, your `array` is not an `array` but an `object`.

You can do something like this:

```
var pseudoArray = { 'index1': 'value1', 'index2': 'value2' };
var pseudoArrayKeys = Object.keys(pseudoArray);
var valueInFirstElementInPseudoArray = pseudoArray[pseudoArrayKeys[0]];
```

Comment: Object.keys does not guarantee order found in object. http://jsfiddle.net/aktufsmp/

Comment: You are right @charlietfl but is the best way to what he wants. Either way, I think either approach for this will be wrong. He is trying to use an object as an array... that is wrong by itself

Comment: Exactly. These Object.keys answers are giving false hope and structure should be changed if order is important

Comment: Not really sure is giving false hope... but it answers the question, it explains the difference between an object and and array... Whether that is a good choice of usage for him or not, that is different... but was not his question.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure that you might be using is definitely an object not an array, let variable name be **arrObj** so you can do something like -:

```
arrObj[Object.keys(arrObj)[0]]
```